# What is an "open graph"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

In an old research paper**, I saw a theorem relating to a correspondence that has an "open graph". I looked for this term in Google, and all I could find was the "open graph" technology of Facebook, which is totally unrelated. So what does it mean that a correspondence has an open graph?

** [Equilibrium in abstract economies without ordered preferences, by Shafer and Sonnenschein](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304406875900026).

I haven't found a free version available online, but, the paper is [summarized in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_economy#Abstract_economy_with_preference_correspondences).

EDIT: I should have googled for [Closed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph) - it is a much more common term.

Comment: Beats me.  It seems like a term that would be defined by the author of said "old research paper."  Perhaps if you give the author and title, Readers could help by identifying earlier publications by the same author, where a definition might have been more natural.  In functional analysis one has a notion of "closed graph" for partially defined functions.

Comment: Just some guesses based on a Google search: (1) https://books.google.nl/books?id=7qR9DUlceOIC&lpg=PA208&ots=6Njqig5mP7&pg=PA207, Definition 5.23; (2) https://books.google.nl/books?id=6RjGDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA57&ots=Q1h8ENEnic&pg=PA33, Definition 3.4; (3) https://books.google.nl/books?id=Ns-5BQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA177&ots=hVQ6tsCfyv&pg=PA177, used in Definition 2ff.

Comment: @hardmath I added the reference.

Comment: Note that http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/research/math/papers/94.pdf seems to be a "working paper" associated with the paper you cite (source: https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:nwu:cmsems:94).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correspondence is simply a set-valued map $\phi: X\to 2^Y$. The graph of $\phi$ is then the set $$\Gamma(\phi)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid y\in\phi(x)\}.$$
If $X$ and $Y$ come endowed with topologies, we can endow $X\times Y$ with the product topology. If the graph of $\phi$ is an open set in the product topology, we say that $\phi$ has an open graph.